# How to query Jira webhooks defined in descriptor of Atlassian Connect app?

Tags: jira, webhooks, jira-plugin

I have a Jira connect app that specifies a number of static webhooks in the app descriptor. The webhooks aren't being fired for some (non-admin) users, which I'm trying to debug. In the [docs](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/v3/api-group-webhooks/), there's a way to query REST (dynamic) webhooks, using the  but this returns an empty list for our app (presumably since the webhooks were declared as a [connect module](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/modules/webhook/)).I've tried this by GETting the `/webhook/failed` and the `/webhook` endpoints.

The app has ADMIN scope, and we have webhooks for a number of events including `jira:issue_created`, although for some users these are never firing.

My question is how can you query webhooks specified by an add-on in a connect descriptor? Is there a way to see failed deliveries or other metadata for webhooks that might have fired?

Thank you!